# SSL_read stuck when no longer receiving response from HTTP server

Tags: c, windows, sockets, ssl, https

When the HTTP server is done sending information, the SSL_read function gets stuck waiting for a response even when the server is done sending data.

I have tried to check for errors using SSLs default error handling, but that would not work since there isnt an error, it simply waits for a response. I have tried making the sockets nonblocking, but it didnt work for the SSL sockets and couldnt find anything online about it. Im using winsock2.

Here is where the problem is:

```
    do {
        bytesRead = SSL_read(ssl, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1);

        
        buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        sscanf_s(buffer, "HTTP/1.%*d %d", &statusCode);
        

    } while (bytesRead > 0);
```

Here is the whole code, slightly edited:

```
int xxx() {

    WSADATA wsaData;
    SSL_CTX* sslContext = NULL;
    
    char* httpRequest = "just the request, not important"

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        printf("Failed to initialize Winsock.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    SSL_library_init();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    sslContext = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_client_method());

    SOCKET socketClient = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (socketClient == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Failed to create socket.\n");
        closesocket(socketClient);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    struct addrinfo* result = NULL;
    if (getaddrinfo("example.com", "https", NULL, &result) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to resolve hostname.\n");
        closesocket(socketClient);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = ((struct sockaddr_in*)result->ai_addr)->sin_addr.s_addr;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(443);

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (connect(socketClient, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Failed to connect to server.\n");
        closesocket(socketClient);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    SSL* ssl = SSL_new(sslContext);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, socketClient);

    if (SSL_connect(ssl) != 1) {
        printf("SSL handshake failed.\n");
        SSL_free(ssl);
        closesocket(socketClient);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    if (SSL_write(ssl, httpRequest, strlen(httpRequest)) <= 0) {
        printf("Failed to send HTTP request.\n");
        SSL_free(ssl);
        closesocket(socketClient);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    char buffer[4096];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    int statusCode = 0;

    do {
        bytesRead = SSL_read(ssl, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1);
        buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';
        sscanf_s(buffer, "HTTP/1.%*d %d", &statusCode);
        

    } while (bytesRead > 0);
    

    SSL_shutdown(ssl);
    SSL_free(ssl);
    closesocket(socketClient);
    WSACleanup();

}
```

Comment: You are just reading arbitrary bytes from the socket in an endless loop until the connection is closed or an error occurs. That is not how HTTP works. You need to actual *PARSE* the response to know HOW to read it correctly and detect WHEN it ends. See my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A65863+http+pseudo) on this subject which explain the logic needed to read HTTP messages properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL_read on a blocking socket will block either until the underlying TCP connection is closed, the SSL session is closed (SSL_shutdown) or error happened. It will not close when *"the server is done sending data"* because it is not known to the socket or SSL session when the server is done.

With HTTP the client can ask the server to close the connection after the response is finished while adding a `Connection: close` header. But note that currently the HTTP request is completely broken and resembles the HTTP protocol in no way.